# merge few lines into one until found special line

Tags: awk, sed

I have a text file with the following format. There is a separator (`*****`) after few random lines like below

```
aa
bb
cc
*****
dd
ee
*****
ff
ggg
hh
ii
*****
```

I'm expecting like below ouput

```
aa,bb,cc
dd,ee
ff,ggg,hh,ii
```

i think awk and sed can help me. but can not figure
it  out exactly.
How do I merge those lines into one?

Thank you.

Comment: What's exactly the problem with `awk` and `sed`? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This awk one-liner should work for your input:

```
awk -v RS='[*]+' -v OFS="," '$1=$1' file
```

test with your data:

```
kent$  cat f
aa
bb
cc
*****
dd
ee
*****
ff
ggg
hh
ii
*****

kent$  awk -v RS='[*]+' -v OFS="," '$1=$1' f
aa,bb,cc
dd,ee
ff,ggg,hh,ii
```

Answer (score 1):

alternative to nice `awk` solution, if your `sed` supports `\n'

```
$ tr '\n' ',' <file | sed 's/,\**,/\n/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
cat in.txt | tr ' ' ',' | tr '\n' ' ' | sed 's/\*\*\*\*\*/\n/' | sed 's/^ //'
```

will result in :

```
aa,bb,cc dd,ee ff,ggg,hh,ii 
ff,ggg,hh,ii dd,ee aa,bb,cc
```

for input lines :

```
aa bb cc
dd ee
ff ggg hh ii
*****
ff ggg hh ii
dd ee
aa bb cc
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;N;/\n\*+$/!s/\n/,/;ta;P;d' file
```

Append another line to the current and then replace its newline by a comma until a line consisting of only `*`'s is encountered. Then print the first line and delete the pattern space.

Answer (score 0):

sed in action

```
sed  -nr '/^[*]+ */!{H};/^[*]+ */{s/.*//g;x;s/\n/,/g;s/^,//g;p}' my_file
```

output

```
aa,bb,cc
dd,ee
ff,ggg,hh,ii
```